# Stretching a button in a grid span

Tags: .net, wpf, .net-4.5, visual-studio-2013

I'm still relatively new to WPF and currently self-training. I use Google to find answers to about 90% of my questions but in this particular case, the answers I've found myself don't seem to work so I'm hoping someone can help me out on SO.

To train myself using WPF and .NET 4.5 with C#, I am writing a calculator app. At the moment I'm trying to get the Equals button (=) to stretch across 2 rows in my grid. So far this is what my XAML looks like:

```
<Window
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:Themes="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Windows.Themes;assembly=PresentationFramework.Aero" x:Class="WpfCalc.MainWindow"
        Title="WPF Calculator" Height="350" Width="525">

    <Window.Resources>
        <Style x:Key="NumberButton" TargetType="Button">
            <Setter Property="Width" Value="40"/>
            <Setter Property="Height" Value="40"/>
            <Setter Property="Margin" Value="5"/>
            <Setter Property="ContentTemplate">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Label Content="{Binding}" FontSize="20" FontFamily="Consolas"/>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </Window.Resources>

    <StackPanel>
        <TextBlock>

        </TextBlock>
        <Grid>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

            <!--Numbers-->
            <Button Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="1" Style="{StaticResource NumberButton}" Content="0"/>
            <Button Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="0" Style="{StaticResource NumberButton}" Content="1"/>
            <Button Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="1" Style="{StaticResource NumberButton}" Content="2"/>
            <Button Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="2" Style="{StaticResource NumberButton}" Content="3"/>
            <Button Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Style="{StaticResource NumberButton}" Content="4"/>
            <Button Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" Style="{StaticResource NumberButton}" Content="5"/>
            <Button Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="2" Style="{StaticResource NumberButton}" Content="6"/>
            <Button Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Style="{StaticResource NumberButton}" Content="7"/>
            <Button Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" Style="{StaticResource NumberButton}" Content="8"/>
            <Button Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="2" Style="{StaticResource NumberButton}" Content="9"/>

            <!--Math Operations-->
            <Button Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="3" Style="{StaticResource NumberButton}" Content="/"/>
            <Button Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="3" Style="{StaticResource NumberButton}" Content="*"/>
            <Button Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="3" Style="{StaticResource NumberButton}" Content="-"/>
            <Button Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="3" Style="{StaticResource NumberButton}" Content="+"/>
            <Button Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="4" Grid.RowSpan="2" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Style="{StaticResource NumberButton}" Content="="/>
        </Grid>
    </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

The very bottom `<Button>` is my equals button. I've set it to have a row span of 2 and what I expected was for the button to stretch vertically to fill in both cells in the Grid. However, it does not. My personal research has shown to use `VerticalAlignment` or `VerticalContentAlignment` to make the button stretch but it doesn't work and remains the same size as the other buttons, just centered vertically in the span area.

Anyone know how I can make this do what I want? Help is appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is probably that the style `NumberButton` sets the button's height to 40.

Try setting the `Height` property in the `<Button>` tag itself to 80, which will take precedence over the styled `Height` setter (see [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms743230%28v=vs.110%29.aspx#listing) for the exact order in which properties will take precedence)

```
<Button Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="4" Grid.RowSpan="2" 
        VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Style="{StaticResource NumberButton}" 
        Content="=" Height="80" />
```

As an alternative, you could also create another style `BasedOn` your `NumberButton` style, like this:

```
<Style x:Key="EqualsButton" TargetType="Button" 
       BasedOn="{StaticResource NumberButton}>
    <Setter Property="Height" Value="80"/>
</Style>
```

Comment: He could just use Height ="Auto" and it will span the rows like he is wanting

Comment: @MarkHall Yes, that would work too since it would be overwriting the styled `Height=40` with `Height=Auto`, which would make it take up all the space that's available to it

Comment: Ah that was an oversight on my part! Thanks for pointing that out. Works now! Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Try adding `Height="Auto"` to that button. It works when I tried it out.